# How to check whether a number is Fibonacci number in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Input: a positive integer.

Output: true / false based on test.

Here is my attempt:

```
(defn is-a-fib? [x]
  "Check whether x is a fibonacci number.
   Algorithm: test whether 5x^2+4 or 5x^2-4 is a perfect square."
  (let [a (+' (*' (Math/pow x 2) 5) 4)                      ; 5x^2+4
        b (-' (*' (Math/pow x 2) 5) 4)                      ; 5x^2-4
        sqrt-a (Math/sqrt a)
        sqrt-b (Math/sqrt b)]
    (or (== (*' sqrt-a sqrt-a)
            (*' (Math/floor sqrt-a) (Math/floor sqrt-a)))  ; Test whether n is a perfect square
        (== (*' sqrt-b sqrt-b)
            (*' (Math/floor sqrt-b) (Math/floor sqrt-b))))))
```

The problem is: this code doesn't work for a large number. I think it may cause stack overflow.
Is there a better way?

Comment: what leads you to believe it causes a stack overflow? do you know what a stack overflow is? (it seems you don't). And no, it's not the problem. The problem is much more likely to reside in floating-point operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Math/pow`, `Math/sqrt`, and `Math/floor` operations work on `double`s which have a limited range of precision, and operations on them will have rounding errors.

If you look at it in this light, things may derail simply owing to rounding, but they will really go wrong when you've exhausted the precision (15–17 decimal digits).

This first *n*th Fibonnacci where this algorithm gives a false positive for the subsequent integer is for the 16-digit integer associated with *n* = 74.

```
(is-a-fib? 1304969544928657)
=> true
(is-a-fib? 1304969544928658)
=> true
```

**Edit**: Adding arbitrary precision solution that avoids `double`s:

The main difficulty is the lack of an integer square root algorithm.

[This Java implementation](http://faruk.akgul.org/blog/javas-missing-algorithm-biginteger-sqrt/) can be translated to Clojure:

```
(defn integer-sqrt [n]
  (let [n (biginteger n)]
    (loop [a BigInteger/ONE
           b (-> n (.shiftRight 5) (.add (biginteger 8)))]
      (if (>= (.compareTo b a) 0)
        (let [mid (-> a (.add b) (.shiftRight 1))]
          (if (pos? (-> mid (.multiply mid) (.compareTo n)))
            (recur a (.subtract mid BigInteger/ONE))
            (recur (.add mid BigInteger/ONE) b)))
        (dec a)))))
```

With that in place, you can define an arbitrary-precision perfect square test:

```
(defn perfect-square? [n]
  (let [x (integer-sqrt n)]
    (= (*' x x) n)))
```

And update your implementation to use it:

```
(defn is-a-fib? [x]
  "Check whether x is a fibonacci number.
   Algorithm: test whether 5x^2+4 or 5x^2-4 is a perfect square."
  (let [a (+' (*' (*' x x) 5) 4)                            ; 5x^2+4
        b (-' (*' (*' x x) 5) 4)]                           ; 5x^2-4
    (or (perfect-square? a)
        (perfect-square? b))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, your explanation is really clear. Then how to make the code work for large numbers?

Comment: @Nick I anticipated your follow-on question and edited the answer to provide an example of how you might revise things to use arbitrary-precision operations. In my opinion, the `Math/sqrt` is the main obstacle to overcome.

Comment: Thank you! The integer-sqrt is the hardest part of the program. You made  the perfect-square as a separate function makes code easy to read. Good to learn!